# Best way to visualize the graph data structure written in Java on a web page with good graphics?

Tags: java, javascript, ruby-on-rails, graph

I am developing a web application that presents a undirected graph data structure on web site but i could not find good way to it efficiently and mobile phone compatible.

I though using java-script or html5 is fastest way but how can i get java data and present it with HTML or java-script.

Or I plan to use Ruby on Rails instead of java but I could nor find a library that is capable to draw such a graph on webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you transform your Java data to JSON (using GSON, for instance: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), and then use a library like gRaphael (http://g.raphaeljs.com/) to visualize it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

For graphs something like [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/), now [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), can provide some pretty awesome results.